# Strange behaviour when creating a function directly from CodeType and FunctionType in python

Tags: python, function

**DISCLAIMER:** I know that what I'm doing should probably never *ever* be done in a real program.

I recently just learnt about python's `types.CodeType` and `types.FunctionType` and it got me interested in creating functions manually via these classes. So as a small test, I started with a function that looked something like this:

```
def x(e, a, b=0, *c, d=0, **f):
    print(a, b, c, d, e, f)
```

and wanted to see if I could move the parameters around to turn it into this:

```
def x(a, b=0, *c, d=0, e=0, **f):
    print(a, b, c, d, e, f)
```

Essentially I want to make an ordinary parameter into a keyword-only argument. This is the code I used to do such a mutation:

```
from types import CodeType, FunctionType

def x(e, a, b=0, *c, d=0, **f):
    print(a, b, c, d, e, f)

code = x.__code__
codeobj = CodeType(
    code.co_argcount - 1, code.co_kwonlyargcount + 1, code.co_nlocals, code.co_stacksize,
    code.co_flags, code.co_code, code.co_consts, code.co_names, ('a', 'b', 'd', 'e', 'c', 'f'),
    code.co_filename, code.co_name, code.co_firstlineno, code.co_lnotab, code.co_freevars,
    code.co_cellvars
    )
new_func = FunctionType(codeobj, x.__globals__, x.__name__, x.__defaults__, x.__closure__)
new_func.__kwdefaults__ = {'d': 0, 'e': 0}
```

Strangely enough the tooltip seems to show up correctly (the little yellow rectangle of text that shows up in the IDLE interpretter when you begin typing a function call), it displays "a, b=0, *c, d=0, e=0, **f". But the behaviour the function had was interesting to say the least:

```
>>> new_func(1)
0 0 () 0 1 {}
>>> new_func(1, 2)
2 0 () 0 1 {}
```

The first parameter was still getting sent in as `e`, and the second element is still getting sent in as `a`.

Is there a way to fix this? If there is, would it require delving into the `code.co_code` and breaking apart the opcodes, or is there a simpler method?

Comment: In your example, you are calling `x`, not `new_func`.

Comment: Whoops, sorry. It still misbehaves when using `new_func` though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Functions and their code objects are tightly coupled. Arguments are handed in as locals, and locals are looked up *by index*:

```
>>> import dis
>>> def x(e, a, b=0, *c, d=0, **f):
...     print(a, b, c, d, e, f)
... 
>>> dis.dis(x)
  2           0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (print)
              3 LOAD_FAST                1 (a)
              6 LOAD_FAST                2 (b)
              9 LOAD_FAST                4 (c)
             12 LOAD_FAST                3 (d)
             15 LOAD_FAST                0 (e)
             18 LOAD_FAST                5 (f)
             21 CALL_FUNCTION            6 (6 positional, 0 keyword pair)
             24 POP_TOP
             25 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             28 RETURN_VALUE
```

Note the integers after the `LOAD_FAST` byte codes, those are indices into the locals array. Reshuffling your arguments did not alter those bytecode indices.

The `code.co_varnames` list is only used for introspection (such as the `dis` output), to map indices back to names, not the other way around.

You'd have to apply surgery to the bytecode to alter this; see the [`dis` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dis.html) for more details.

If you are using Python 3.4 or newer, you can make use of the new [`dis.get_instructions()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dis.html#dis.get_instructions) to iterate over an information-rich sequence of `Instruction` objects, which *should* make such surgery doable. Look for the `LOAD_FAST` instructions, and map indices as you produce new bytecode.

`Instruction` objects don't have a method (yet) to convert them back to bytes; adding one is trivial:

```
from dis import Instruction, HAVE_ARGUMENT

def to_bytes(self):
    res = bytes([self.opcode])
    if self.opcode >= HAVE_ARGUMENT:
        res += (self.arg or 0).to_bytes(2, byteorder='little')
    return res

Instruction.to_bytes = to_bytes
```

Demo:

```
>>> [ins.to_bytes() for ins in dis.get_instructions(code)]
[b't\x00\x00', b'|\x01\x00', b'|\x02\x00', b'|\x04\x00', b'|\x03\x00', b'|\x00\x00', b'|\x05\x00', b'\x83\x06\x00', b'\x01', b'd\x00\x00', b'S']
>>> b''.join([ins.to_bytes() for ins in dis.get_instructions(code)]) == code.co_code
True
```

Now all you have to do is map the `.arg` argument of instructions with `.opname == 'LOAD_FAST'` to a new index.

Comment: Hmmm, so I assume there would be no easy way of fixing this since I would have to change the integers in the bytecode after every `LOAD_FAST` to the variable I shuffled?

Comment: @user3002473: exactly, you have do do bytecode surgery here.

Comment: Alright thanks, I'll look into `dis.get_instructions` to see if what I want to do is plausible for my application :)

Comment: @user3002473: The `Instruction` objects do not, currently, have any method to produce the corresponding bytecode bytes again, but producing such a method should not be hard.

Comment: @user3002473: added a method to convert `Instruction` objects back to bytes, so now you can process these objects in a stream.